# Identify unsupported devices

Tags: android

I'm in the process of releasing our first Android app. In the developer console it says

Supported devices: 11141
Unsupported devices: 2868

My question is the any way to determine what are the unsupported devices?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the answer is no. Your app would identify the minimum SDK versions involved and the devices would not be up to that standard. You should not have to worry about this as the play store wouldn't let those affected users downloading your app anyway for installation on their unsupported device.